# Is there an analog of a Chern-Simons formula for the pfaffian $Pf(F)$ of a $SO(2n)$ curvature $F$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, spin-geometry, chern-simons-theory

..something similar to $tr(A \wedge dA + 2/3 * A \wedge A \wedge A)$ for $n = 2$ ?